# Safe to store moved object in member reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, move-semantics

Is the following code safe, or might `m_s` be a dangling reference after constructing `C`?

```
class C {
public:
    C(string&& s) : m_s{s} {} 
private:
    string& m_s;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not safe, consider the following example:

```
C c(std::string("42"));
```

where you pass in the constructor a temporary. This way you create a dangling reference.

Comment: Would making `m_s` a `const string&` make it safe? I know there are different lifetime extension rules where references and const references are concerned.

Comment: @Danra no it wouldn't. It would keep being a dangling reference even if const qualified.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any situation in which the original code would *not* create a dangling reference?

Comment: @Danra `std::string s; C c(std::move(s));` wouldn't be a dangling reference because `s` outlives `c`. But people don't expect you to hold on to rvalue references; they expect you to do something with them straight away.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe. Also member const references do not extend the lifetime of a temporary (so that's not an option either). What you should do instead is move construct a value out of your temporary to "absorb" that into your class :

```
class C {
public:
    C(string&& s) : m_s{std::move(s)} {} 
private:
    string m_s;
};
```